# how to add event listener to determine what the coordinates inside a div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Suppose that I have div box that is 200px by 500px.

The objective is to add an event listener to determine the x and y coordinates inside of this div that is clicked.

How can that be down in React?

Comment: Listen for `click`, and then use `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no effort -- [No effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9078341) - this is not the purpose of this site. We are happy to answer questions - not complete your assignment for you. Give this a try, come back with some code that doesn't work and we'll help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the position of the element, plus [`MouseEvent.clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) and [`MouseEvent.clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY) to get the click coordinate.

See demo:

```js
function XYComponent() {
  const go = (e) => {
    const offsets = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const y = e.clientY - offsets.top;
    const x = e.clientX - offsets.left;
    console.log(x, y);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="demo" onClick={go}>AAA</div>
      <div class="demo" onClick={go}>BBB</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<XYComponent />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
.demo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```